# How to create a specific alias based on a generic typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Consider the following interfaces:

```
export interface FooInterface<T, O extends FooOptions<T>> {
  items: T[];
  options: O;
}

interface FooOptions<T> {
  doSomething: (e: T) => void;
}
```

Now whenever i need to do something with this I need to repeat T. For example:

```
const t: FooInterface<string, FooOptions<string>> = {
  items: ["a","b","c"],
  options: {doSomething: (e) => {
      console.log(e);
  }}
}
```

Now, repeating is boring, is it possible to create a type or interface where T should be string for both types, or redefine the interfaces somehow, so that I write something like this instead:

```
const t: FooInterfaceString
//or
const t: FooInterfaceOfType<string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers here are correct, but I want to add that you might consider using [generic parameter defaults](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults) if you are usually (but not always) going to just pass in `FooOptions<T>` as the type of `O`:

```
interface FooOptions<T> {
    doSomething: (e: T) => void;
}

// note how O has a default value now
export interface FooInterface<T, O extends FooOptions<T> = FooOptions<T>> {
    items: T[];
    options: O;
}
```

That lets you just leave out the `O` parameter when you intend it to just be `FooOptions<T>`:

```
const t: FooInterface<string> = {
    items: ["a", "b", "c"],
    options: {
        doSomething: (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the event that you actually want `O` to be more specific than `FooOptions<T>` (that's why you have it as a separate parameter, right?), you can still do it:

```
interface MoreOptions {
    doSomething: (e: string) => void;
    doNothing: () => void;
}

const u: FooInterface<string, MoreOptions> = {
    items: ["d", "e", "f"],
    options: {
        doSomething(e) { console.log(e); },
        doNothing() { console.log("lol nvm"); }
    }
}
```

Oh, and if `T` will usually be `string` then you can add a default for it too and then `FooInterface` without parameters will be interpreted as `FooInterface<string, FooOptions<string>>`:

```
export interface FooInterface<T = string, O extends FooOptions<T> = FooOptions<T>> {
    items: T[];
    options: O;
}

const t: FooInterface = {
    items: ["a", "b", "c"],
    options: {
        doSomething: (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this was really exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

how about :

```js
type FooInterfaceString = FooInterface<string, FooOptions<string>>;
```

also, maybe consider this if it fits your design:

```js
export interface FooInterface<T> {
  items: T[];
  options: FooOptions<T>;
}
type FooInterfaceString = FooInterface<string>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [TypeScript alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

```
// Declaration
type FooInterfaceOfType<T> = FooInterface<T, FooOptions<T>>;

// Usage
const t: FooInterfaceOfType<string>;
```